# Random order display in v-for with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I'm using MongoDB and vue.js to display a content from my db, the content is returned as an object with several properties containing other objects.

But the problem is that the `v-for` function of vue.js is randomly displaying the content.
In my DB, the content is sorted by field creation, and stay in this position.
When I get the object in `this.statics`, if I console.log it, I have those fields by alphabetic sort. But what I don't understand is : when i display it with a `v-for` they never come out in the same order.

here is my vue code :

```
h3 Static elements
.content-wrap(v-if="Object.keys(statics).length > 0")
  .menu-admin
    .btn(v-for="(content, key) in statics" @click="activeStatic = key") {{key}}
  .content(v-for="(content, key) in statics" v-if="key === activeStatic")
    h3 {{key}}
    .line
    .wrap(v-for="(item, keys) in content")
      h4 {{keys}}
```

the problem is where `keys`is.

here is my function who returns my object:

```
getStatics(statics) {
  Promise.all(Object.keys(statics).map((key) => {
    return PartsService.fetchDataWrap({
      id: statics[key]
    }).then((res) => {
      statics[key] = res.data.values
    })
  })).then(() => {
    this.statics = statics
  })
},
```

console.log for `this.statics` (who never change) :

```
{__ob__: Observer}
  my static bloc: Object
    image1: (...)
    image2: (...)
    text1: (...)
    text2: (...)
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem ? I've got same issue and trying to solve this but still not achieved.

Answer (score 0):

`v-for` for object doesn't guarantee orders when iterating over object's key value pairs. So my suggested ways to solve it is:

Use a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property to sort the `Object.keys(statics)` array, something like `sortedStaticsKeys`, and then iterate using the sorted key array.

Then the template would be something like:

```html
h3 Static elements
.content-wrap(v-if="sortedStaticsKeys.length > 0")
  .menu-admin
    .btn(v-for="key in sortedStaticsKeys" @click="activeStatic = key") {{key}}
  .content(v-for="key in sortedStaticsKeys" v-if="key === activeStatic")
    h3 {{key}}
    .line
    .wrap(v-for="(item, keys) in content")
      h4 {{keys}}
```

I just changed your template in plain text with no actual code running, however it should work this way.